# be demanded + to infinitive or that clause

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, to-infinitive

He was demanded “to confess” to the robbery.

He was demanded “that he should” confess to the roberry.

I wonder whether these two sentences are correct. When we use “demand” as in a passive voice, can we use “to infinitive” or “that clause”?

Comment: In  English we can't use _demand_ in the same way as _ask_. It means 'ask **for**' or 'ask a question sternly'. You could say _The police demanded a confession from him_ or _"Confess to the robbery!" the inspector demanded._

Comment: What @KateBunting said. But you *can* use several other verbs which are far more forceful than ***asked*** for such contexts. *He was **made / coerced / compelled / forced / obliged / pressured** to confess*.

Answer (score 1):

A more normal construction would be: "It was demanded that he confess to the robbery"  or "They demanded that he confess to the robbery"

Note that I didn't use quotes within either of my examples.